# How to hide W3 Total Cache from non admins?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

I would like to be able to hide W3 Total Cache from non admins. How can I go about doing so?

The following code I tried implementing in my functions.php file does not work:

```
function hide_w3tc() {
    if (!current_user_can('super_admin')) {
        remove_submenu_page('admin.php?page=w3tc_dashboard');
    } 
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_w3tc');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `remove_menu_page()`, so you code example would be like:

```
function hide_w3tc() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_network')) {
        remove_menu_page('w3tc_dashboard');
    } 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_w3tc',11);
```

where we use a priority greater than the default of `10`, since the *W3TC* menu page is added via

```
add_menu_page('Performance', 'Performance', 'manage_options', 'w3tc_dashboard', '', 'div');
```

Comment: ok great, by the way you are using a 'super_admin' capability but I usually see the 'manage_network' capability used instead.

Comment: I used super_admin as I made a custom user group. I suppose manage_network has more coverage of all the permissions underneath that umbrella?

Comment: ok I was just wondering where it came from, since it is not listed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities ;-)